# Excel download issue in .Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, excel-2003

Getting com exception, not sure whether it is due to special characters in a particular column or the data being huge in a particular column.

The error we are currently getting is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC)

- Excel version is 2003
- 24 columns
- 20000 rows
- a lot of special characters some 20 or so
- source code is VB

There is one or two such columns. We have recently migrated from `.Net 1.1` to `.Net 3.5`. **It was working fine in .Net 1.1**. If the particular column which has special characters is removed, then it works fine.

Code which we are using

```
intRows = parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).dtblData.Rows.Count
intColumns = parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).dtblData.Columns.Count
ReDim arr_strData(intRows - 1, intColumns - 1)
For i = 0 To intRows - 1
    For j = 0 To intColumns - 1
        arr_strData(i, j) = parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).dtblData.Rows(i).Item(j).ToString
    Next
Next
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).strDataSheet).Activate()
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).strDataSheet).Range("A" & parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).intStartingRow & ":" & strRange & (intRows - 1 + parr_objReportsData(intLoopCounter).intStartingRow)).value = arr_strData
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(strDocsPath & strFileName)
```

Comment: What excel version, how many columns, how "huge", what "special characters", which com-exception, what source code???

Comment: Excel version is 2003, 24 columns , 20000 rows, a lot of special characters some 20 or so source code is VB. There is one or two such columns. We have recently migrated from .Net 1.1 to .Net 3.5. It was working fine in .Net 1.1. The error we are currently getting is System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC). If the particular column which has special characters is removed, then it works fine.

Comment: Please help on this. Sorry for the question being ambiguous.

Comment: Instead of commenting you should edit your question to add new informations(I've already sorted it out). But you should also show the VB.NET code that generates the excel and writes it to the response. It would also be helpful to see some sample data of the columns that are causing this error.

Comment: I have added the VB.NET code. Please check and help on this.

Comment: Since i cannot answer it yet because it's not reopened(needs 5 votes), i will try to answer it via comment. It seems to be a localization issue. Try to set CurrentCulture to "en-us". `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")`. http://www.made4dotnet.com/Default.aspx?tabid=141&aid=15

Comment: @TimSchmelter Question reopened. Feel free to post your solution as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a localization issue. Try to set `CurrentCulture` to "en-us".

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
            New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
```

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369/en-us
- http://www.made4dotnet.com/Default.aspx?tabid=141&aid=15